# how to make a multiple filter query in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have 3 query filter that will be used to search. The first query is selected option query, the second query is date query when i want to search betwen date start and date end query. the last query is about searching name, etc. The only working query just the last one. What happens with my code, i thought there doesn't any problem with my code

Here is my code that using filter

**filtercontroller.php**

```
public function viewType(Request $request, ReportViewAll $reportview){

    $reportview = $reportview->newQuery();
    if ($request->has('program')) {
        if($request->input('program') == 'reportall'){
            $reportview;
        }
        elseif($request->input('program') == 'reportactive'){
            $reportview->where('crewprogram_isdisabled', '=',0);
        }
        elseif($request->input('program') == 'reporthistory'){
            $reportview->where('crewprogram_isdisabled', '=',1);
        }
    }

    if(($request->has('datestart') && $request->has('dateend'))){
        $reportview->whereBetween('crewprogrammemo_placement_date', 
        array($request->input('datestart'), $request->input('dateend')));
    }

    if($request->has('search')){
        $reportview->where ( 'employee_nik', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
                ->orWhere ( 'employee_nama', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
                ->orWhere ( 'show_focus_id', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
                ->orWhere ( 'show_name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" );
    }

    return $reportview->get();

    // return view('CrewProgram.ReportView.index', compact('reportview'));
}
```

What should i do for the three of them to start working, not just 1 query that's working

**Edited**

```
public function viewType(Request $request, ReportViewAll $reportviewall){

    $reportviewall = $reportviewall->newQuery();

    if ($request->has('program')) {
        if($request->input('program') == 'reportall'){
            $reportviewall;
        }
        elseif($request->input('program') == 'reportactive'){
            $reportviewall->where('crewprogram_isdisabled', '=',0);
        }
        elseif($request->input('program') == 'reporthistory'){
            $reportviewall->where('crewprogram_isdisabled', '=',1);
        }
    }

    if(($request->has('datestart') && $request->has('dateend'))){
            $reportviewall->whereBetween('crewprogrammemo_placement_date', 
            array($request->input('datestart'), $request->input('dateend')));
    }

   If($request->has('search')){
        $reportviewall->where(function($query) use($request) {
            $query->where('employee_nik', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
                ->orWhere ( 'employee_nama', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
                ->orWhere ( 'show_focus_id', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
                ->orWhere ( 'show_name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" );
        });
    }


    $reportviewall = $reportviewall->get();
            return view('CrewProgram.ReportView.index', compact('reportviewall'));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your queries is that when you pass a search filter, you are chaining multiple `orWhere()`'s to the query, which means that any query to one of these filters that is true will be returned, it won't matter if any of the other filters were false, the solution to this is to wrap the search filter in a callback function, like this:

```
if($request->has('search')){
    $reportview->where(function($query) use($request) {
        $query->where('employee_nik', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
            ->orWhere ( 'employee_nama', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
            ->orWhere ( 'show_focus_id', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
            ->orWhere ( 'show_name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" );
    });
}
```

Comment: If you don't/won't have any other `orWhere()` filters you can also simply move your search filters to the top, for it to be used as your first filter, that way you can filter out your search first, then on top of that filter out the rest of the query.

Comment: @RobertKujawa after i try to change into your suggestion, i'm getting null array, like ```[]``` there is no item in my search filter

Comment: That's weird, it should definitely work. Can you share your updated code so I can help you?

Comment: @RobertKujawa i edited my question with updated code, i think the proble within the second, query, because when i delete that query, the code are working fine, but when i input query that using ```whereBetween``` it give me null

Comment: All looks good to me. You say that you get null when you pass in a 'datestart' and 'dateend', maybe that is because you have no 'crewprogrammemo_placement_date' between those dates, that also pass your program and serach filters. If that's the case, I believe that is your expected behavior? have you tried passing in all 3 query filters where you have at least one row that is true to all? See if that returns some data.

Comment: oh god, yeah you're right, there is no  between those dates, so basically, ```whereBetween`` is translated like this ```'datestart' > (wherebetween) < 'dateend'``` it can be translated like this ```'datestart' >= (wherebetween) <= 'dateend'```, then how come?

Comment: yes i try to passing query that's true to all but the first program query and the search query didn't work, the only working query is the date query. but if i remove the date query and just using search query (without the date and program query), its work, it's the same with program query(without the date and search query). but when i input date query, neither the search and the program query is working

Comment: That means the problem is your `whereBetween()` query, Are you sure you are passing the correct format of the date to your query? If you are using MySQL it should be 'YYYY-MM-DD', that means `$request->input('datestart')` and `$request->input('dateend')` must have this format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211879/discussion-between-ricky-reza-muhammad-and-robert-kujawa).

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

- **OR**
  using `orWhere()` :

  ```
  Model::query()->where([])->orWhere([])->get();
  ```
- **AND** using 2nd array :

  ```
  Model::query()->where([['column1' , '!=' , 'value1'] , ['column2' , '=' , 'value2'] , ['column3' , '<' , 'value3']])->get();
  ```